# JMS topic vs Multicast in Apache Camel

Tags: apache-camel

If we have to send a message to multiple end points, in Camel there  is a multicast EIP. What if the end points are ONLY JMS endpoints? In that case, I feel that topic is better that multicast EIP. Or is there any specific behaviour difference or pattern which differentiates these two approaches if the end points are JMS endpoints? Please clarify, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we have to send a message to multiple JMS end points, then we need to use **Topic** instead of **multicast** as it will be a better and less time consuming approach. Send a message in a topic through which  consumers receive message and do different process.